# Array filtering in JavaScript is returning an empty array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object, filter

```js
// console.log("Testing Merging of data");

const Array_1 = [{ class_1: 4, HeadTeacher: "Mrs Joe" }];
const Array_2 = [{ class_1: 10, HeadTeacher: "Loveth" }];
const Array_3 = [{ class_1: 1, HeadTeacher: "Itunu" }];
const Array_4 = [{ class_1: 1, HeadTeacher: "John" }];

const result = [...Array_1, ...Array_2, ...Array_3];

const Final = result.filter((item, index) => {
  return item.class_1 === 10 && item.class_1 === 1;
});

console.log(Final);

//  Expected result
// [{ class_1: 1, HeadTeacher: "Itunu" }, { class_1: 1, HeadTeacher: "John" }; ];

// Out put ; Empty array []
```

I have an array of objects which I'm filtering to return certain results based on my filter criteria. but all I did was just returning an empty array.

Comment: `item.class_1 === 10 && item.class_1 === 1` means that you want `item.class_1` to be equal to 10 **and** equal to 1.  How would that be possible?

Comment: `item.class_1 === 10 && item.class_1 === 1`  Are you only looking for items where class_1 is both 10 and 1 at the same time?

Comment: I want the object where class_1 === 10 and class_1 === 1

Comment: Don't you want to do an || instead then.

Comment: If they're only arrays of one object couldn't they just be objects?

Comment: If you want items where class_1 is equal to 10 OR equal to 1, use the || instead of &&

Comment: //  Expected result
    // [{ class_1: 1, HeadTeacher: "Itunu" }, { class_1: 1, HeadTeacher: "John" }; ];

Comment: My expected result above

Comment: Your conditional makes no sense though. They can't be the same value at the same time. Are you sure you understand how filter works? Not trying to be a dick.

Comment: I'm just learning all these things though

Comment: when i do this const Final = result.filter((item, index) => {
  return item.class_1 === 10;
});
it returns where class_1 === 10

Comment: Thank you, everyone... I changed the && to || and it worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why your array output is different from your expected result is your condition when returning.

- You are using logical AND (&&). You should change && to ||.

Answer (score 2):

Use **OR(||)** operation instead of **AND(&&)**.

Correct Code ->

```
const Array_1 = [{ class_1: 4, HeadTeacher: "Mrs Joe" }];
const Array_2 = [{ class_1: 10, HeadTeacher: "Loveth" }];
const Array_3 = [{ class_1: 1, HeadTeacher: "Itunu" }];
const Array_4 = [{ class_1: 1, HeadTeacher: "John" }];

const result = [...Array_1, ...Array_2, ...Array_3];

const Final = result.filter((item, index) => {
  return item.class_1 === 10 || item.class_1 === 1;
});

console.log(Final);
```